# How to apply grub theme to a live usb?

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, theme, bootable

This is my setup,

- I Have installed `grub` on the usb using `grub-install` command in the `/boot` directory.
- I copied 3 iso's on the usb
- Manually created a `grub.cfg` file to boot into the iso's.

So I want to use the starfield theme that comes by default installed with grub.

Now, using the `GRUB_THEME` variable in `/etc/default/grub` does not work as I am unable to run the `grub-update`(update-grub) command. Is there any way I can use the theme?

Comment: Why are you unable to run the update command?

Comment: @JesseKeilson Because the update command is installed on the computer and it update the cfg file for computer. How would i make it update cfg file for usb?

Answer (score 3):

first install Strafield theme, remember to copy font, ... files from your /usr/share/grub/ directory to the /boot/grub/ directory on the usb.

```
vi /etc/default/grub
```

add this:

```
GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub2/themes/starfield/theme.txt"
```

or 
               "/usr/share/grub/themes/starfield/theme.txt"

then :

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /media/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

check following files in the /boot/grub/ directory on the usb:

- unicode.pf2
- png.mod
- vbe.mod
- vga.mod
- gfxterm.mod
- part_msdos.mod
- fat.mod
- the image image (bg.png)

Delete the file /boot/grub/grubenv from the stick

put this code in /boot/grub/grub.cfg file:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod fat
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set <your usb UUID>
loadfont /boot/grub/unicode.pf2
set gfxmode=1024x768
insmod vbe
insmod vga
insmod gfxterm
terminal_output gfxterm
insmod png
if background_image /boot/grub/bg.png ; then
  set color_normal=white/black
  set color_highlight=magenta/black
else
  set menu_color_normal=white/black
  set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
fi
```

check the following:

- the USB should have a msdos MBR insmod part_msdos
- the USB should have a FAT32 file-system > insmod fat
- the `/boot/grub/` is in the first partition > `set root='(hd0,msdos1)'`.
- your graphics card supports the 1024x768 mode > set to your needs

Comment: Welcome to U&L. When answering please look at how to format code ( select and click `{}` above the edit box, and leave an empty line before a list of bullet items. You can see how I changed your code to look somewhat better by selecting the link `edited` above the last editors name (mine in this case).

Comment: This answer almost worked. the only problem was that using `/etc/default/grub` doesn't work because one cannot update grub using `grub-mkconfig` as that command would update the computers grub and not usb's grub. I ended using the `set theme= /foo/theme.txt` and `export theme` commands directly in grub.cfg file.

Comment: I have awarded the bounty as this answer helped, but I can't accept the answer until it is edited so that it works.

Comment: the     grub-mkconfig   should be used for the /media/boot/grub2/grub.cfg not the /boot I edited it .

Comment: Are you sure this works? For me, it simply overwrites the USB grub.cfg file with a cfg file for my computer. the `-o` flag simply provides the output destination, the `grub-mkconfig` command would still look at where it is installed(which is the computer)

Answer (score -1):

You can apply any theme you like on the grub bootloader by
following these commands.

1. first become the root user if you don't know how to do that then just google it. but here is the command for becoming root sudo -s and type the password of the user you're logged in with
2. go select a theme on gnome.look.org
3. if you have downloaded right and click on extract here
4. then go to the terminal and type ls cd your folder that you have saved the theme/and be sure to insert the slash
5. there will be some things red and blue
6. the blue one would be your theme
7. then type cd (the name of your theme and slash if you don't insert the slash there will be an error ) don't copy-paste the name of your theme
8. then type ./install.sh
   it will display something blue and yellow wait for 2 mins then restart the computer and boom the theme is applied