# How to make grub-mkconfig work on a usb device?

Tags: grub2, live-usb

AFAIK `grub-mkconfig` and `grub-update/update-grub` commands only run on the device that they are installed on.

I want to run the commands on a usb drive, but

- I don't know how to install them on the usb
- I can't make the ones that are installed on my computer to run on usb(i.e they should update the usb's grub.cfg file)

How can I do either of them?

BTW I am using manjaro KDE

Comment: What is it exactly what you are trying to acomplish?

Comment: @YoMismo http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224695/55673

Comment: Then mount your usb in /mnt, `mount --bind` /dev /sys /proc under mnt's respctive ones and `chroot` to your /mnt, modify any needed file and run `grub-mkconfig`

Comment: @YoMismo Can you write an answer? I didn't get your comment properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mount your USB in /mnt: `mount /dev/your_USB /mnt`
2. `mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`
3. `mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`
4. `mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`
5. `chroot /mnt`
6. Modify GRUB config files.
7. `grub-mkconfig`

your chroot needs a fully working bash in its space (and probably a lot of other tools), with all needed libraries. you can find those with `ldd` and you need to copy them in the right place (same tree as your regular root)

[this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/441534/how-to-use-the-chroot-command-on-linux/) provides some automation hints

Comment: Beware - I find that it puts incorrect 'search hints' in the `grub.cfg` that can stop the target machine from finding kernel and initrd.  You may need to clean it up (`sed` helps).

Comment: I get this error `chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try `chroot /mnt /path/to/your/shell`

Comment: @YoMismo I tried `sudo chroot /mnt /usr/bin/bash` it gives
`chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/bash’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Does /usr/bin/bash exist?

Comment: Yes it exists. BTW please include @RegisteredUser tag in your comments so that I am notified about them.

Comment: That's weird @RegisteredUser, `chroot`'s output states it can't find it. Does `bash` also exists in your mounted /mnt? maybe `chroot` needs it in both sides.